# using Buttons to retrieve data from database

Tags: android

I have connected a database in my Android Application. Now I have created a button and when it is clicked, that should get the next data from the table of database. I have cursor and he moveToFirst() and moveToNext() methods in my code. also I have set onclick listener to my button. but in output when I click the button, its is not fetching the next data from database

heres the part of code where I have tried to set on click listener for button

```
 c=myDbHelper.query(myDbHelper.DB_PATH +"/MainTable",null, null, null, null,null, null);
        c.moveToFirst();

                 myques=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.question);
                 myrg=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.rg1);
                 myc1=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio0);
                 myc2=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio1);
                 myc3=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio2);
                 myc4=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio3);
                 NxtQues=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1); 

               myques.setText(c.getString(1));
               myc1.setText(c.getString(2));
               myc2.setText(c.getString(3));
               myc3.setText(c.getString(4));
               myc4.setText(c.getString(5));
               NxtQues.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View V)
                {

                    c.moveToNext();
                }

            });
```

what changes should I make in this code to set on click listener in a proper way.

Comment: How do you know that the cursor has not moved?  You are not updating the UI anywhere.

Comment: im a beginner in android. will the moveToNext() method move the cursor to next set of data? and will the setText method again set the text for the next retreival of data?

Answer (score 0):

So in your code is a few problems. At first here:

```
c = myDbHelper.query(myDbHelper.DB_PATH +"/MainTable", ...);
```

As first parameter of query() method is "raw" tablename so you can't assign there full path of your database(if it isn't real tablename...), it's wrong. Just assign **MainTable** like this:

```
c = myDbHelper.query("MainTable", null, null, null, null, null, null);
```

Then your logic about fetching data from database is not good at all. You assigned values to your widgets only once and no more. They never be refreshed, you need to call as many times setText() method as you want to update widget's content. Actually you don't update them.

You need to change your logic to:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View V) {
  if (c.moveToNext()) {
     myques.setText(c.getString(1));
     myc1.setText(c.getString(2));
     myc2.setText(c.getString(3));
     myc3.setText(c.getString(4));
     myc4.setText(c.getString(5));
  }
}
```

**Recommendation:**
When you are using "getters" methods of Cursor, i recommend you to use column names to get columns indexes:

```
myques.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("columnName")));
```

Comment: thanks sir!! actually im trying to develop a small quiz application where i used a database to hold all the question and its multiple choice options. and i retrieve the data for each and every question. so i created a button NextQuestion and whenever it is clicked, the next set of data, it should fetch :)

Comment: @ArjunViswanathan ok so check my asnwer and update your onClick method like i mentioned.

Comment: its working sir!!! thanks a lot again :) and when i assign just my table name in Query method, its not working and its working only when i give the table name along with its path, tats d reason i gave it like tat

Comment: i used coloumn index method too :) what is the advantage in using index rather than Ids like 1,2,3,4??

Comment: @ArjunViswanathan if you don't know about projection of columns and you don't know so, if somecolumn is exactly at 3 index, or at 4. then is more efficient to get index based on column name, that is much more safer. and you are welcome, dont remember to accept answer >}